# When did the NSURLSessionTaskDelegate be set?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

i just learn to use the NSURLSession API , and i found that we just set the NSURLSessionDelegate  when we create the session like this

```
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:self.operationQueue];
```

and  we did not set the NSURLSessionTaskDelegate ,but the NSURLSessionTaskDelegate methods will be called too , it seems that the system will call the NSURLSessionTaskDelegate methods on a object comply NSURLSessionDelegate?

### update demo code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<NSURLSessionDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    
    NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    
    NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.baidu.com"]];
    
    [task resume];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    
}
```

Comment: It should not happen. Please post which delegate method is getting called.

Comment: @New16 ,i just add the demo code ,and the - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error will be called even i didnt set the task delegate

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiondatadelegate. According to this it will call those delegates by default.

Comment: so ,it seems that , the session delegate object  must be the sesstion task delegate too ?

Comment: So, you have created a task in the defined session right. So, the session delegate will make sure the other delegates(taskDelegate, dataDelegate, downloadDelegate) methods are also called based on which one you create(task, data, download).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're saying is that you created a class that implements methods in both the `<NSURLSessionDelegate>` and `<NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>` protocols, but you only declared that it implements the `<NSURLSessionDelegate>` protocol.  You then passed this as the delegate when creating a session, and you're confused by why the session task delegate methods are also called.

First things first, there's only one delegate per session.  It handles events related to the session and events related to the task.  The delegate methods are grouped into multiple protocols to make them easier to document and understand.  The distinction between task and session delegate methods has no run-time significance.

The `NSURLSession` class comes pre-compiled by Apple.  It wasn't compiled using your headers, and it therefore has no idea whether the header for the class object that you passed in has a `<NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>` decoration or not.  Those decorations only have meaning in the context of telling the compiler that the class should contain those methods.  If you pass an instance of that class to a method whose parameter type says that the passed-in object must conform to the `<NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>` protocol and your class doesn't, the compile will fail.  Similarly, if you are missing required methods in the protocol, compiling your class will fail.  Beyond those two purposes, however, those decorations are basically just for programmers' benefit.

Additionally, because all of the `NSURLSession` delegate methods are optional, the session cannot assume that its delegate will support any particular methods based on what protocols it claims to conform to anyway.

For these reasons, at the run-time level, a session determines whether to call each delegate method by asking the delegate object if supports that method.  If it says "YES", then the session calls that method.

Because your class provides an implementation for both the task and session delegate methods, the class automatically says "YES" when asked if it supports those methods, so `NSURLSession` calls them at the appropriate time.